# Problema al formar un árbol binario, me cambia valores a null y no logro identificar porque

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, árboles-binarios

buenas noches/tardes/días.
Estoy intentando hacer un árbol binario aparir de una lista doblemente enlazada, la idea es que reciba una operación como: 5*9*8= y me forme un árbol con esa cadena. No he incluido lo que debe hacer cuando ingreso los operadores de suma y resta porque este error no me deja avanzar. **EL ERROR SE ENCUENTRA EN LA CLASE lista EN EL METODO insertarArbol();**

Mi problema es que al llegar a la linea 50 cuando trato de asignarle un valor nulo a la hoja izquierda de la raíz de mi árbol, me cambia el valor de todas las variables a null. No logro identificar por que... si alguien puede darme una pista lo agradecería mucho. Dejo mi código a continuación:

```
public class Nodo {
//Variables
 private char dato;
private boolean flag = false;
private Nodo izq;
private Nodo der;
private Nodo Raiz;


//Constructor 
public Nodo(){}
public Nodo(char dato){
this.dato = dato;
}
//Para saber el nodo izquierdo
public Nodo getNodoIzquierdo(){
return izq;
}
//Para saber el nodo derecho
public Nodo getNodoDerecho(){
return der;
}
//Se crea nodo derecho
public void setNodoDerecho(Nodo nodo){
der = nodo;
}
//Se crea nodo Izquierdo
public void setNodoIzquierdo(Nodo nodo){
izq = nodo;
}

public char getDato(){
return dato;
}

public void setDato(char dato)
{
  this.dato = dato;
}


public boolean getFlag() {
    return flag;
}


public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
    this.flag = flag;
}

/**
 * @return the Raiz
 */
public Nodo getRaiz() {
    return Raiz;
}

/**
 * @param Raiz the Raiz to set
 */
public void setRaiz(Nodo Raiz) {
    this.Raiz = Raiz;
}
```

}

```
public class Lista 
{
    private Nodo Raiz;
    Nodo nuevo;
    Nodo arbol;
    Nodo actual;

    public Lista()
    {

    }

    public void insertar(char caracter)
    {
        nuevo = null;
        if(getRaiz() == null)
        {
            Raiz = new Nodo(caracter);
        }
        else if (getRaiz() != null)
        {
            nuevo = new Nodo(caracter);
            getRaiz().setNodoDerecho(nuevo);
            nuevo.setNodoIzquierdo(getRaiz());
            Raiz = nuevo;
        }


    }
    public void mostrar()
    {
        actual = Raiz;

        while(actual != null)
        {
            System.out.println(actual.getDato());
            actual = actual.getNodoIzquierdo();
        }
    }
    public Nodo insertarArbol()
    {

        actual = Raiz;

        while(actual != null)
        {
            if(arbol == null)
            {
                nuevo = actual;
                //El problema esta aqui abajo
                nuevo.setNodoIzquierdo(null);
                arbol = nuevo;
                actual = actual.getNodoIzquierdo();
                actual = Raiz.getNodoIzquierdo();

            }
            else if(actual.getDato() == '*' || actual.getDato() == '/'  )
            {
                nuevo = actual;
                nuevo.getNodoDerecho().setFlag(true);
                nuevo.getNodoIzquierdo().setFlag(false);
                nuevo.setNodoIzquierdo(actual.getNodoIzquierdo());
                nuevo.getNodoIzquierdo().setNodoIzquierdo(null);
                nuevo.getNodoIzquierdo().setNodoDerecho(null);
                nuevo.setNodoDerecho(actual.getNodoDerecho());
                nuevo.getNodoDerecho().setNodoDerecho(null);
                nuevo.getNodoDerecho().setNodoIzquierdo(null);
                nuevo.setRaiz(arbol);
                arbol = nuevo.getNodoIzquierdo();
                actual = actual.getNodoIzquierdo().getNodoIzquierdo();
                actual.setNodoDerecho(null);

            }
            else
            {
                actual = actual.getNodoIzquierdo();
            }

        }
    }

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ArbolBinario 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            //Declaracion de variables
            String Operacion;
            Nodo nodo;
            Lista lista = new Lista();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            char caracter;
            //Ingresar operacion
            System.out.println("Ingresa una operacion");
            Operacion = sc.next();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < Operacion.length() ; i++)
            {
                caracter = Operacion.charAt(i);
                lista.insertar(caracter);
            }
            lista.mostrar();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            lista.insertarArbol();       
        }
  }
```

Comment: que tal? no veo donde declaras tu nodo raiz en tu arbol, que es lo primero que tiene que hacer, un nodo que apunte a null, y luego insertar. que seria la base o el tronco de tu arbol.
te dejo un projecto similar solo que lo hice en js. para que veas la logica y te pueda servir
https://github.com/jcsanchez1/ArbolBinarioWeb

Comment: ¿Por qué la clase para el arbol se llama lista? ¿Y por qué has definido cuatro nodos? _raiz, nuevo, arbol y actual..._ Es confuso y un arbol a priori solo debería tener un único nodo: el nodo raiz. Seguramente en algún sitio estás confundiendo uno de esos cuatro y borrando lo que no toca.

Comment: Ah y tampoco tiene mucho sentido que todos los nodos tengan un enlace al nodo raíz... Eso ya no es un arbol y se complica todo. Date cuenta de que si modificas el nodo raiz (por ejemplo si unes dos subarboles a partir de un nuevo nodo raiz) entonces tendrías que recorrer todos los nodos y modificar todos los enlaces a raiz...